refresh dbgrid after use select in commandtext datasnap client in delphi
In Delphi I have a client in Datasnap and  I have Dbgrid when I use
ClientDataSet1.CommandText := 'select * from tlogin where id=2';
ClientDataSet1.Open;

My Dbgrid doesn't change. How can I refresh Dbgrid in Datasnap client. In Datasnap client I have sqlconnection1 and DSProviderConnection1 and ClientDataSet1 and DataSource1.
I need to refresh Dbgrid.

In the datasetprovider set AllowCommandText to true.

Close the ClientDataSet first.
